# Token is always null in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get a token to use cloud messaging in my app with the following simple code :

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

I have tried to look everywhere on StackOverflow for people who had the same problem and couldn't find any solution... I have, of course, followed the official Google Documentation about the installation (several times) and my token was never generated.

Any idea why I can't get a valid token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I managed to find the solution by myself, it took me a lot of time to figure it out so I thought it would be a good idea to share the solution in case someone gets the same issue.

So the problem came from the fact that I used this line in my `AndroidManifest.xml` (inside `<application>` tag) :

```
tools:node="replace"
```

This had to be removed or changed by the following :

```
tools:node="merge"
```

Otherwise, Firebase will not work in your app. At least, it's how I fixed my app to finally get a valid token!

Hope this will help someone else!

Comment: Thanks sooooooooooooooooooooo much you saved my life

Comment: did not work for me. Still getting null. any one have any more ideas

Comment: @AmmarBukhari : try to uninstall app. Research when get Firebase token to see :0

Comment: Thanks very very very much

Comment: You saved me ton of time.

Comment: You are awesome!! I was being crazy with it. Now it works. But can you please clarify why it worked? Thanks a ton anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Make Sure that your Firebase "**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**" file is directly under the package name tree "com.company"
Don't put them in the separate subpackage like "com.company.services".
This is because your google-services.json will look for the files directly under "com.company" directory.

Add the following in your manifest **application** tag below meta tag (if any)

```
   <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

You will get your TOKEN on the     **public void onTokenRefresh()** method

PS: Make sure date is correct on your device and having the **latest google-services.json** from your project console.

Comment: How does date should be considered as a relevant?

Comment: @SrikarReddy Check under Settings that "Automatic date & time" is toggled on. The point is that you should not be far ahead or behind from the current time. Once my clock was set 3 days ahead, that when I faced this issue.

Comment: I have MyFirebaseInstanceIDService in a subpackage and it works correctly in com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0