# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating Firebase Cloud messaging in android

app build.gradle looks like this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

class path in apllication level build.gradle is

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
```

and my manifest is something like that

```
<service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
       </intent-filter>
  </service>
       <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_artize_a" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

My problem is that When I try to get `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()` it returns null. so I am unable to get Token.

Even `onNewToken` of `MyFirebaseMessagingService` is not fired a single time in app.

Can Some one tell me why i am getting `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() null` here thanks in advance.

Here i am trying to get firebase token

```
private void getFirebaseToken(){
        FirebaseInstanceId firebaseInstanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();
        if(firebaseInstanceId == null){
            return;
        }


        firebaseInstanceId.getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    return;
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show where in your code you're calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()`

Comment: May be If you are calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()` on UIThread it is giving you null. Try to execute it on separate thread.

Comment: I am calling FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() in OnCreate method of an activity

Comment: @m0skit0 I am adding my code to getFirebasecode in question

Comment: Well, you're doing just what Mahavir Jain said.

Comment: @MahavirJain FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() returns null on noUIThread also

Comment: But you just said you're calling `getFirebaseToken()` at `onCreate()`.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes i have change it letter as mahavir said. But the result is same...

Comment: How have you changed, can you explain?

Comment: @m0skit0 I have tries two ways.First time i called this method in AsyncTask's `doInBackground` it doesn't work then i make a `thread` and call this method it also not worked...............

Comment: @NavinGupta I am having the same issue , did you find any solution ?

Comment: @alphaguy the steps seems correct, so it could be a problem with your app's manifest, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784860/token-is-always-null-in-firebase)

Comment: Also make sure you checked that GooglePlay is installed on your phone. `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable();`

Answer (score 7):

After Long research, I found that `tools:node="replace"` in the manifest file is making FCM to not work.

Change `tools:node="replace"` to `tools:node="merge"`

go through this link

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/477

Answer (score 3):

try to replace in your Android Manifest application tag
with the below attributes

> android:allowBackup="false"
>   tools:node="merge"
>   tools:replace="android:label,android:allowBackup"

Comment: Thank you Vinoth! Do you know what causing this?

Comment: @JerabekJakub when you build the apk file, gradle not include content provider ( FirebaseInitProvider class) in android manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Having `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();` on the UI thread shouldn't be a problem. I have the following in the onCreate method of the MainActivity and it works perfectly (probably not recommended by google and others):

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(instance_id_completion_listener);
```

Try the following steps:

1. Add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'` to the app build.gradle file.
2. Remove, but back it up, all manifest entries related to Firebase. I don't have any in my manifest file however I am only using Firebase to get an instance id.
3. If one hasn't done so already go to `https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup` and add Firebase to Your Android Project.

One could also try the following:

```
private void getFirebaseToken(){

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                return;
            }

            Log.d("getFirebaseToken", "Successful");

            // Get new Instance ID token
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

        }
    });
}
```

For testing purposes only as this is not a good idea on the UI thread, 
try the following:

```
private void getFirebaseToken(){
    FirebaseInstanceId firebaseInstanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(firebaseInstanceId == null){
        return;
    }


    firebaseInstanceId.getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                return;
            }

            // Get new Instance ID token
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a missing declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application ... >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

After adding it, the issue was resolved.